# Open Azure App Service Endpoint to Only a Few Applications

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I've implemented an ASP.NET Web API app as an Azure App Service.  It has an App Registration, everything works as expected.  I can hit the API from a browser and see all the JSON it returns.  Now what I want to do is ensure that nothing except one or more applications from a set list can actually get anything from this endpoint.  The applications needing access will all be custom ones in my organization/tenant.  With all the flexibility and options, I'm having a very hard time determining what I need to do to lock the API down in this way.

I was envisioning having some client secrets the API knows about, and let the authorized applications supply them.  Other methods would certainly be acceptable.

I'm certain this must be a duplicate question, but due to the plethora of information out there, and the myriad techniques for running applications on Azure, I can't seem to find just the right solution for my simple case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have implemented interactive browser redirect-based authentication on the API.

Instead, you should implement JWT authentication on the API. 
Then in Azure AD you can define permissions that can be granted to client applications. 
In that way you can control which app can do what.

https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-1

https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will review it over the next few days and let you know if I have any more questions.  I've enjoyed your blog for some time now, too.  Keep it up!

Comment: Following the first two links is a little bit difficult, presumably because of changes made to App Registrations since it was written, and maybe to the values needed in appsettings.json on the API project end.

Comment: True the registration portal was updated :) The same things should still apply even though may be in slightly different places. Anything specific you can't find?

Comment: I think my issue is that there are so many flows and grant types, and I wasn't quite sure of which did what.  Now I'm pretty certain what I really want is a way to support both Client Credentials (for other server-side applications to call this API) and JWT implicit flow (for accessing the API on behalf of users from React and other JS applications.  I may just need to write a new question, but do you happen to have a good resource for authenticating by Client Credentials/Secret?

Comment: I should have added, I'll be aiming to use AuthorizeAttributes on the controllers in the API to select between whether the caller must be using client secrets, implicit flow access tokens, or either.

Comment: Well, I have an article for defining permissions: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-2 Apps using client credential flow to call your API will need application permissions defined and assigned to them.